# How to change a range value in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, index-error

I am getting an index error from trying to access values from a list after removing values whilst inside of a for loop. How do I change the range value in the for loop after each iteration? The function itself is to taken a list as an input and reverse the list in a new list but only by removing elements from one list into another so that the input list ends up empty.

```
def minsort(lst):
    new_lst = list()
    counter = 0
    while len(lst) > counter:
        smallest = lst[0]
        for i in range(1, len(lst)):
            if smallest > lst[i]:
                smallest = lst[i]
                new_lst.append(smallest)
                lst.remove(smallest)
                smallest = lst[0]
            else:
                new_lst.append(smallest)
                lst.remove(smallest)
    return new_lst

lst = [3,1,2]
print(minsort(lst))
```

Error that I am getting:

```
    if smallest > lst[i]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Edit: I am doing this without any inbuilt functions such as sorted()

Comment: You are removing items from the list `lst.remove(smallest)` that is shrinking the size of the list and giving you index error. Remove that and it should work. But you are not changing the `counter` value at the moment, so it is infinite loop for now.

Comment: @hadik It's not infinite because `len(lst)` changes.

Comment: @Barmar Oh yes, i meant, it will be infinite if you try to fix it by removing the `lst.remove`.

Comment: I have to use lst.remove as I am trying to have an empty input list by the end, I guess I could try and reset the list right at the end? Edit: I also just tried to run it without the .remove and the output was [1,2,1,2,1,2] which is not correct

Comment: I believe your algorithm is inherently flawed, there are a lot more issues in it than just what you're currently facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to sort a list in ascending order you could use:

```
new_lst = sorted(lst)
```

EDIT*

well, this seem to work without any built-in functions:

```
def minsort(lst):
    new_lst = []

    while lst:
        smallest = None
        for item in lst:
            if smallest == None:
                smallest = item
            elif item < smallest:
                smallest = item
        new_lst.append(smallest)
        lst.remove(smallest)
    return new_lst
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that I am trying to do it without any of the inbuilt functions like sorted.